# Regex expression to match a URL that has no query String

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, friendly-url

Wordpress Context BTW. To put into htaccess.
I need it to match the Website URL only if there are no parameters.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$`

I tried reading on it and playing with this line, but nothing worked.
TIA for any tips.

EDIT:
I need the regex to match the the website URL when there is no path and no parameters. I want to redirect users only when they access the main page. But using  this is making internal linking of wordpress fail, so I'm using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home/?$` and redirecting them when they access home only.
I'm trying to read documentation but is going above my head.

TIA for any tips.

Edit 2: Original question is answered, created new SO question

Comment: You tried "reading on it"? I wonder what you read. Because what you ask is clearly explained in the documentation of the rewriting module you are using... https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thank you! I guess I really didn't know where to look for it

Comment: @Goma, your question is completely changed now,IMHO rather than changing your base question please open new question. Because answers which were given will not make any sense then. Please revert your changes to your question and open a new question,thank you.

Comment: In general: the apache http server has a really impressive documentation: precise, clear, great examples. Which actually is typical for OpenSource software...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put a condition for NO query string present in a URL you should try something like. Variable you are looking in htaccess is `QUERY_STRING` and yes concept/logic to match nothing is same like you used but we don't want `/` here(which is for REQUEST_URI in your attempted code), so put `^$` to match NULL instead here.

```
your rules here....
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
Your rules further here...
```

***NOTE:*** How conditions work in htaccess is if conditions are getting satisfied then only their respective actions/rules will be executed so please use it accordingly. Here is the documentation of apache(refer arkascha's comment too under question) https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: I forgot to mention that I didn't want the path to matched either. So I put `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$` and it does exactly what I need. Thank you for poiting in the right direction. I will approve as I forgot to mention I wanted it to match without params or path.

Comment: @Goma, For query string's test to null this should work fine, cheers and happy learning :)

Comment: I actually still don't understand. When I finally deployed it live, it stopped working properly, and it affected all sorts of internal linking inside WordPress, but not where I wanted it to.
I think it was working in the first time because the page was cached somewhere? So I used at alternate method, and it is working, but I'd rather use the original intended method.

Comment: @Goma, I am sorry your question is completely changed now, IMHO rather than changing your base question please open new question. Because answers which were given will not make any sense then. Please revert your changes to your question and open a new question, thank you